# How can I link to a result in Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

Sometimes I want to link to a research article on Google Scholar, as the latter contains a list of sources where we can retrieve the research article. Is there any good way to link to a specific result, just like we can link to an insert in StackExchange, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean like this for your example? http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=966870769675810229&hl=en&as_sdt=0,18

Comment: Thanks, ideally there wouldn't need to have any source to be able to get a link, but otherwise yes clicking on "All X versions" is a pretty good solution.

Comment: So you want to be able to say email someone a link, and when they click, it shows them the extract and where they can find the research paper in question? Or that you want them to see the search results where the research paper is one of the matching results?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise The first option: when they click, it shows them the extract and where they can find the research paper in question. This way it reduces the odds of them being confused about which articles I am talking about.